# How to compare the dataframe column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a names column, date arrival (type date) and price( type numeric) like this

```
names    Datearriv   price
SUV      2019-01-16  84,35
HOR      2020-02-28  130,45
SUV      2019-01-16  235,12
```

Actually I have a problem with my R project. I would like to compare the names, if they are the same, I compare the arrival date if it is the same, I compare the price of the stay and the program has to delete the line with the highest price of stay, i.e. the one with the tax.

I wrote this code but it makes mistakes.
Here's my code and the dataframe

```
for(i in 1:96){nom=data[i,2] date = data[i,4] prix = data[i,8] z = i+1 for(j in z:97){ if(data[j,2] == nom){ if(data[j,4] == date){ if(data[j,8]>prix){ data = data[-j,] else{data = data[-i]}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
d <- read.table(text="
  names    Datearriv   price
  SUV      2019-01-16  84,35
  HOR      2020-02-28  130,45
  SUV      2019-01-16  235,12", header=TRUE
)


library(dplyr)

# Note that your variable is not numeric yet
d <- d %>%
     mutate( price = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", price )))

# now can filter
d <- d %>% 
     group_by(names, Datearriv) %>% # define the groups
     add_count(name="N") %>% # check how many observations per group
     mutate( max = max(price) )  %>% # check the max price 
     filter(!(max==price & N>1) ) %>% # we can drop the observation if teh price is max and we have more than one
     dplyr::select(names:price) # select relevant columns

d
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   names, Datearriv [2]
  names Datearriv  price
  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>
1 SUV   2019-01-16  84.4
2 HOR   2020-02-28 130.
```

Comment: in case this answer solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers